# All fillTexted text crammed in one place in HTML5 canvas

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

I want to display an hexagonal grid where each cell displays its coordinate in the system (thus the top leftmost cell will have `a1` written in it, the one immediately right to it will have `b1` written in it, etc).
The code below is meant to achieve this (and nearly does it).
However all the texts are crammed in one small place (even though I specified the location on line 48 of the code, and this location seems correct since the rest of the image is fine). What am I doing wrong ?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hex board</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var r = 20;
  var w = r*2*(Math.sqrt(3)/2);
  var ctx;
  var mainWidth = 850;
  var mainHeight = 600;
  var dim = 11;
  var i,x,y, txt;
  var alphabet =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

  function textFromCoordinates(x,y)
  {
    return(alphabet[x]+(y+1));
  }

  function drawHexagon(c, x, y, r)
  {
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(x, y-r);
      for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
          c.lineTo(x+r*Math.cos(Math.PI*(1.5+1/3*i)), y+r*Math.sin(Math.PI*(1.5+1/3*i)));
      }
      c.closePath();
      c.fill();
      c.stroke();
  }

  function draw()
  {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mainWidth, mainHeight);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;

      ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
      for(y=0; y<dim; y++)
      {
          for(x=0; x<dim; x++)
          {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + (x+241) + "," + (y+220) + ",178)";
              drawHexagon(ctx, (x+y)*w - (y-4)*(w/2), (y+2)*1.5*r, r);

              txt = textFromCoordinates(x,y);
              ctx.font = 'italic 40pt Calibri';
              ctx.fillStyle = "black";
              ctx.moveTo((x+y)*w - (y-4)*(w/2), (y+2)*1.5*r);
              ctx.fillText(txt,mainWidth/dim,mainHeight/dim);
          }
      }

  }


  function load()
  {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("output");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      draw();
  }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
    <canvas style="position:absolute,top:0px,left:20px" width="850" height="600" id="output">Canvas not supported...</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the text at the same coordinates as the hexagon:

```
ctx.fillText(txt,(x+y)*w - (y-4)*(w/2),(y+2)*1.5*r);
```

Also I've changed the font to a smaller size, and I'm aligning it around the center:

```
ctx.font = 'italic 16px Calibri';
ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
```

I hope this is what you need.

```js
var r = 20;
  var w = r*2*(Math.sqrt(3)/2);
  var ctx;
  var mainWidth = 850;
  var mainHeight = 600;
  var dim = 11;
  var i,x,y, txt;
  var alphabet =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

  function textFromCoordinates(x,y)
  {
    return(alphabet[x]+(y+1));
  }

  function drawHexagon(c, x, y, r)
  {
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(x, y-r);
      for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
          c.lineTo(x+r*Math.cos(Math.PI*(1.5+1/3*i)), y+r*Math.sin(Math.PI*(1.5+1/3*i)));
      }
      c.closePath();
      c.fill();
      c.stroke();
  }

  function draw()
  {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, mainWidth, mainHeight);
      ctx.lineWidth = 1;

      ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
      for(y=0; y<dim; y++)
      {
          for(x=0; x<dim; x++)
          {
              ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + (x+241) + "," + (y+220) + ",178)";
              drawHexagon(ctx, (x+y)*w - (y-4)*(w/2), (y+2)*1.5*r, r);

              txt = textFromCoordinates(x,y);
              ctx.font = 'italic 16px Calibri';
              ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
              ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
              ctx.fillStyle = "black";
              
              ctx.fillText(txt,(x+y)*w - (y-4)*(w/2),(y+2)*1.5*r);
          }
      }

  }


  function load()
  {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("output");
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      draw();
  }


load()
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas style="position:absolute,top:0px,left:20px" width="850" height="600" id="output">Canvas not supported...</canvas>
```